# Scala var best practice - Encapsulation

Tags: scala, class, private, encapsulation

I'm trying to understand what's the best practice for using vars in scala, for example

```
class Rectangle() {
 var x:Int = 0
}
```

Or something like:

```
class Rectangle() {
 private var _x:Int = 0
 def x:Int = _x
 def x_(newX:Int):Unit = _x=newX
}
```

Which one can be considered as better? and why?
Thank you!

Comment: The second one is equivalent to the first one. The second one may be better in the case where you may want to give broader visibility to the _read_ than the write. However, the best practice will always be not to use one at all, but if needed keep is scope as minimum as possible, so again IMHO I would go with the second one and use `private[this]` instead.

Comment: Without the actual use-case it is difficult to say, as you ought to use case class or vals nor vars so it really depends on the use-case. based on your question I would use a case class Rectangle(x:Int)

Answer (score 1):

As Luis already explained in the comment, vars are something that should be avoided whenever you are able to avoid it, and such a simple case like you gave is one of those that can be better designed using something like this:

```
// Companion object is not necessary in your case
object Rectangle {
   def fromInt(x: Int): Option[Rectangle] = {
     if(x > 0) {
       Some(Rectangle(x))
     } else None
}
final case class Rectangle(x: Int)
```

It would be very rare situations when you can't avoid using vars in scala. Scala general idiom is: "Make your variables immutable, unless there is a good reason not to"

Comment: Yes. You're right. Added final. For companion object it was more meant to be used for more complex calculation rather than this simple example. In such basic example, it is enough to use case class only.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to understand what's the best practice for using vars in scala, […]

Best practice is to not use `var`s at all.

> Which one can be considered as better? and why?

The second one is basically equivalent to what the compiler would generate for the first one anyway, so it doesn't really make sense to use the second one.

It *would* make sense if you wanted to give different accessibility to the setter and the getter, something like this:

```scala
class Rectangle {
 private[this] var _x = 0
 def x = _x
 private def x_=(x: Int) = _x = x
}
```

As you can see, I am using different accessibility for the setter and the getter, so it makes sense to write them out explicitly. Otherwise, just let the compiler generate them.

Note: I made a few other changes to the code:

- I changed the visibility of the `_x` backing field to `private[this]`.
- I changed the name of the setter to `x_=`. This is the standard naming for setters, and it has the added advantage that it allows you to use `someRectangle.x = 42` syntactic sugar to call it, making it indistinguishable from a field.
- I added some whitespace to give the code room to breathe.
- I removed some return type annotations. (This one is controversial.) The community standard is to always annotate your return types in public interfaces, but in my opinion, you can leave them out if they are trivial. It doesn't really take much mental effort to figure out that `0` has type `Int`.

Note that your first version can also be simplified:

```scala
class Rectangle(var x: Int = 0)
```

However, as mentioned in other answers, you really should make your objects immutable. It is easy to create a simple immutable data object with all the convenience functions generated automatically for you by using a case class:

```scala
final case class Rectangle(x: Int = 0)
```

If you now want to "change" your rectangle, you instead create a new one which has all the properties the same except `x` (in this case, `x` is the only property, but there could be more). To do this, Scala generates a nifty `copy` method for you:

```scala
val smallRectangle = Rectangle(3)
val enlargedRectangle = smallRectangle.copy(x = 10)
```

Comment: The idea of using explicit return types is more to communicate intent and ensure the compiler guarantee correctness rather than removing cognitive load of the programmer. Yes, for you as the writer is obvious than `x` is an **Int**, but it may not be for the reader nor for the user and even less for the next writer. It wouldn't be too difficult to break binary compability without nobody noticing it by changing `0` to `0.0` by mistake.